# Show file names which did not match in a while loop

Tags: find

I have a file called `files.txt` which contains some file names inside. I have a command that reads this file and execute a `find` to return to me which file names it has found. I'd like to know how can I do the opposite, what I want is to show what file names it did NOT find.

Example:

```
$ ls
file1  file2  file3  files.txt
$ cat files.txt
file1
file2
file3
file4
$ while read x; do (find . -iname "$x"); done < files.txt
./file1
./file2
./file3
```

In this example, I want it to show `file4` in the results, because this file name is in the .txt, but it does not exist in the folder.

Comment: Uhh but how can you tell then what has been found and what hasn't? Wouldn't you rather print `file4 not found`?

Comment: Do you really need to descend into subdirectories (as `find` does, by default) or just check for existence in the top level directory? Do you really need to match case-insensitively?

Comment: @steeldriver it would be good to descend, but if it's not possible, it's ok to search only in the current folder, no problem!

Comment: Well I'm not going to say it isn't *possible* to do it recursively - however it's straightforward to test file existence in the current directory using the shell's `test` operator ex. `[ -e "$x" ] || printf '%s\n' "$x"`

Comment: Does this include directories names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep` (for files in the current folder, assuming their names don't contain newline characters)):

```
$ grep -v -i -F -x -f <(printf '%s\n' *) files.txt
file4
```

Options:

- `-v` invert the match, select non-matching lines
- `-f` `printf '%s\n' *` lists the files in the current directory and is used as pattern input file for `grep`.
- `-F` interpret patterns as fixed strings (instead of regular expressions)
- `-x` match whole lines
- `-i` case insensitive match (like for your `-iname`).

Comment: `printf '%s\n' *` matches also directories, anyway +1

Comment: It also doesn't work for hidden files. But in `bash` you could use `printf '%s\n' {*,.*}`.

Comment: @guillermochamorro, _directories_ are just one of many types of files (regular, symlink, device, fifo...), the OP didn't say anything about excluding them.

Comment: In `bash`, you'd rather use the `dotglob` option. You'd also want the `failglob` option to avoid running `printf` if there's no matching file.

Comment: Although this answer has been accepted (which means it is good enough for the user), it doesn't actually care whether the filenames can be found in a lower subdirectory or not. This is in contrast to the search that the code in the question carries out, which _does_ search in subdirectories.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, but I think that should be clear as noted in the first line of my answer. It's also in no way perfect regarding hidden files or if there are no files in the folder as already noted (but we also don't know which shell OP is using).

Answer (score 2):

Using `find`:

```bash
while IFS= read -r name; do
    if [ -z "$(find . -iname "$name")" ]; then
        printf 'Not found: %s\n' "$name"
    fi
done <files.txt
```

This loops will read a filename at a time from the `files.txt` file and will search the entire hierarchy beneath the current directory for this name, case-insensitively.  If the name is not found (`find` does not output anything), a message to that effect is displayed.

If you want to make sure that the `find` command only looks for regular files (not directories etc.), add `-type f` to that command.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead of using `find` if the depth is one directory:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do 
  [[ -f "${file}" ]] && echo "${file} exists" \
  || echo "$file doesn't exist"; 
done < files.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
files=(*(ND))
list=(${(f)"$(<files.txt)"})

not_found=(${list:#(#i)(${(~j[|])files})})
if (($#not_found)); then
  echo "Not found:"
  printf ' - %q\n' $not_found
fi

not_in_list=(${files:#(#i)(${(~j[|])list})})
if (($#not_in_list)); then
  echo "Unexpected files (not in files.txt):"
  printf ' - %q\n' $not_in_list
fi
```

It's doing a case-insensitive subtraction between the list of files in the current directory (`$files` array) and the list of files in `files.txt` (`$list` array).

`zsh` does have an array subtraction operator (`${array1:|array2}`) but we can't use it here if we want to be case-insensitive.

Instead we use the `${array:#pattern}` operator which expands to the elements of the `$array` *except* those that match the `pattern`.

Here the pattern is built by joining with `|` (`j[|]`) the elements of the other array, and using the `extendedglob` `(#i)` operator for case-insensitive matching.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this snippet from your command line to see the non existent files:

```
$ < files.txt xargs ls -lLd > /dev/null
```

The existing files will not show up since they will be swallowed by the null bucket whereas, since we did not redirect the stderr, the non existing ones will be shown on the terminal.